# How would you implement a self relation for the MegaProtoUser?

Tags: scala, orm, lift

I'm trying to implement a a relation for the user class modelling the "friends" concept with the Lift Mapper framework. My attempt goes something like this

```
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] {
    override def dbTableName = "users" // define the DB table name
    override def screenWrap = Full(<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
               <lift:bind /></lift:surround>)
    // define the order fields will appear in forms and output
    override def fieldOrder = List(id, firstName, lastName, email,
                          locale, timezone, password)

    // comment this line out to require email validations
    override def skipEmailValidation = true
 }

class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] with OneToMany[Long,User]
{
   def getSingleton = User // what's the "meta" server
   object friends extends MappedOneToMany(User, User.id)
}
```

but it fails to compile because of a type mismatch

```
[error]  src/main/scala/code/model/User.scala:30: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : net.liftweb.mapper.MappedLongIndex[code.model.User]
[error]  required: net.liftweb.mapper.MappedForeignKey[Long,?,code.model.User]
[error]   object friends extends MappedOneToMany(User, User.id)
[error]                                                     ^
```

What would be the way to go about this?

Regards

Comment: What do the User companion object look like?

Comment: Just copied from the examples

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message you see that the OneToMany helper needs a *foreign* key in the "many" end of the relation pointing back to this "one". User.id is the primary key and therefore doesn't fit.

If you think about it what you want is really a ManyToMany-relationship.

That you can create like this:

```
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User] with MappedManyToMany {
```

...

```
object friends extends MappedManyToMany(Friends, Friends.friend, Friends.friendee, User)
```

where you have a join table:

```
class Friends extends Mapper[Friends] {
  object friend extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User) {
    override def dbIndexed_? = true
  }
  object friendee extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User) {
    override def dbIndexed_? = true
  }
  def getSingleton = Friends
}
object Friends extends Friends with MetaMapper[Friends]
```

If you want the friend relation to be reflexive, you'll have to do some further work.

This is an extremely late answer I guess. I would suggest posting to the lift mailing list for extremely fast replies: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/liftweb